# Would storing a very large string to sharedpreferences cause problems?

Tags: android

I have a json file containing data dat I download from the web. I'd Like to store this data so my other activities can use it, and not have to re-download it. The file is about 90kB, and could grow in the future to maybe double that. My gut tells me I should store it as a file in assets. But of course storing it as a string in shared preferences seems a lot simpler, so I wonder, why not?

Would storing a very large string to sharedpreferences cause problems, such as lag or memory problems? What are the implications?

Comment: You cannot store a file in assets at run time.

Comment: not a file, a string. I edited the post, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: add some point it makes the sharedpreferences a bit missused. Why not store it in the private folder, thats pretty easy to do using Context#openFileOutput

Comment: I'll be a little more direct.  `SharedPreferences` should *not* be used for storing data.  It's designed, and probably tested, for small key value pairs to store state between instances of your application.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/SVTxgNi3HyE so I don't think you are going to have any issues

Comment: Because when I store my json string to a file, then read it back, it loses its formatting (ie new lines) and becomes unreadable to the Json parser.

Comment: It will lose **formatting** anyway... but new lines ARE NOT formatting. Maybe it will change from Windows to UNIX line terminators? i.e. ASCII 13 + 10 will become ASCII 10...

Comment: Artoo could you explain more?